# Multiple SubReport Display in a single Report Object

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I added multiple sub reports in the details field of a crystal report. But when i did this, i couldn't see the sub reports when I click "Main Report Preview". I know how to add sub reports and other necessary things.
**So, my question is, is it possible to add multiple sub reports in a single crystal report?**
My scenario is, I have a patient table. And Investigation table and TreatmentPlan table.
I want to display the data of Investigation and TreatmentPlan and WorkDone table in the report of the Patient table as subreport. Is it possible?
I have [Googled](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1280&bih=675&q=multiple+subreport+in+crystal+report+sql&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)
and searched in [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=crystal+report+multiple+subreport) earlier but the answers i found there are not relevant to my problem. So, waiting for your suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, it is possible.

I recommend for testing your subreports, color them or use borders so you can see where they are on the report in preview mode. You can also click/select a subreport from the designer and see it selected in preview. That will help in debugging.

Other than that, I would need more information to answer this question.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to follow your suggestions. And then give you feedback.